# weird animation with rotateX and rotateY in 2D transform

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I don't understand why rotateX and rotateY animation in 2D transform will move so weird like [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzmrxP#anon-login)

who can explain it, thanks

the demo code is

pug html

```
.ar
.ar2
```

css

```
body { background: black;}


@keyframes wing3{
  0%{transform: rotateX(50deg)}
  50%{transform: rotateX(70deg)}
  100%{transform: rotateX(50deg)}
}
@keyframes wing4{
  0%{transform: rotateY(50deg)}
  50%{transform: rotateY(70deg)}
  100%{transform: rotateY(50deg)}
}

.ar {
  width: 40px; height: 5px; background: #fff;
   animation: wing3 1.2s infinite;
}

.ar2 {
  width: 40px; height: 5px; background: #fff;
   animation: wing4 1.2s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not werid but logical. You are rotating on the X/Y axis so from our perspective your don't see any rotation but only a size changing.

Here is a classic rotation done the on Z axis:

```css
.b {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
  margin:50px;
  animation:change 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes change{
  to {
    transform:rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
</div>
```

Our element is rotating at the center going from `0` to `90deg`. Now imagine your are looking to this rotation from the bottom. You will simply see a reduced width.

Here is the different frames:

```css
.b {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  margin:50px 10px;;
}

body {
 margin:0;
 font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(40deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(60deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(80deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
</div>
```

Now let's look at this from the bottom:

```css
.b {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  margin:50px 5px;
}
.a {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  margin:50px 10px;
}
body {
 margin:0;
 font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(40deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(60deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(80deg)">
</div>
<div class="b" style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
</div>
<br>
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="a" style="transform:rotateY(40deg)">
</div>
<div class="a" style="transform:rotateY(60deg)">
</div>
<div class="a" style="transform:rotateY(80deg)">
</div>
<div class="a" style="transform:rotateY(90deg)">
</div>
```

So the blue part is our perception of the Z rotation if we look at it from another direction which is equivalent to an Y rotation. And you also have the same effect using a scale transformation since this one will do the same thing from our perception:

```css
.b {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  margin:50px 5px;
  animation:rotate 4s infinite linear;
}
.a {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  margin:50px 10px;
  animation:scale 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate{
  to {
    transform:rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes scale{
  to {
    transform:scaleX(0);
  }
}

body {
 margin:0;
 font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
</div>

<br>
<div class="a">
</div>
```

In order to see this differently, you can add some perspective and you will make the rotation more close to what we see in a real world:

```css
.b {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  margin:50px 5px;
  animation:rotate-1 4s infinite linear;
}
.a {
  width:100px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  margin:50px 10px;
  animation:rotate-2 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate-1{
  to {
    transform:perspective(45px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-2{
  to {
    transform:perspective(45px) rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
body {
 margin:0;
 font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
</div>

<br>
<div class="a">
</div>
```